# How can I find google business/place ID for a service area?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-my-business-api

I need your help about how can I get the business/PlaceID for a business that doesn't have a specific address.
It's a service provider (contractor) for the whole city. Therefore, the address is the name of the city and I can't find it using the placeid search.

Here is one of the for example:

[Google Map Search Results Link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Air+Supply+Heating+%26+Air+Conditioning/@36.3388231,-116.1182118,7.89z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sair+supply+heating+and+cooling+las+vegas!3m4!1s0x80c8c36c00000001:0xb93f69ff6d72da!8m2!3d36.1697979!4d-115.1397479)

As you can see it show the whole Las Vegas city as the business location, Now if you try to search using google placeid finder you won't find it:

[Google Place ID Finder Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder)

Your help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the Place ID finder on the Google My Business support page:

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/faq#how-to-find-placeid

https://support.google.com/business/answer/7035772#place_id

This Place ID finder shows also the Service Area Businesses. I tried with your example and it worked fine

[image]

Comment: It's working on the google place id page however I want to use it on my own web app and the same code with my API key doesn't work, I can't find this business.

Comment: Unfortunately, Places API excludes SABs from their search. There was a feature request in Google issue tracker, but Google rejected it. Please have a look at this comment from Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828187#comment20

Comment: They mentioned there that those who have been authorized to use GMB API will have an option to view SAB, my project has been authorized too but I still can't see SAB in my results.